# How to measure delay in video streaming?

Tags: video-streaming, html5-video, webrtc

I have created a video conferencing and video streaming application using webRTC. It is working perfectly fine. But how can I measure the delay in the transmitting and receiving sides. Are there any utilities for it ?

Answer (score 2):

Enter URL "chrome://webrtc-internals/" in your Chrome browser. It has lots of interesting send and receive network stats which will give you lots of useful data. Hopefully that helps with measuring delay.

Comment: It's not simple, but you can get the same data via the `RTCPeerConnection` `getStats()` method. There's an example at  https://webrtc.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/samples/js/demos/html/constraints-and-stats.html.